# Minesweeper program using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, tkinter, minesweeper

I have complete my minesweeper game using Tkinter and would like to know ways to improve. I also have a question for extra features: does anybody know a way to have a opening start, like google minesweeper does where it breaks open a bunch of squares? Here is my code, accepting all comments:

*Please criticize, readability comments and performance comments accepted*

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import sys
import applescript
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

def printArr():
    for row in arr:
        print(" ".join(str(cell) for cell in row))
        print("")

def createBoard(length, width):
    global arr

    arr = [[0 for row in range(length)] for column in range(width)]

def placeMine(x, y):
    ydim, xdim = len(arr), len(arr[0])

    arr[y][x] = 'X'

    if (x != (xdim - 1)):
        if arr[y][x+1] != 'X':
            arr[y][x+1] += 1 # center right

    if (x != 0):
        if arr[y][x-1] != 'X':
            arr[y][x-1] += 1 # center left

    if (x != 0) and (y != 0):
        if arr[y-1][x-1] != 'X':
            arr[y-1][x-1] += 1 # top left

    if (y != 0) and (x != (xdim - 1)):
        if arr[y-1][x+1] != 'X':
            arr[y-1][x+1] += 1 # top right

    if (y != 0):
        if arr[y-1][x] != 'X':
            arr[y-1][x] += 1 # top center

    if (x != (xdim - 1)) and (y != (ydim - 1)):
        if arr[y+1][x+1] != 'X':
            arr[y+1][x+1] += 1 # bottom right

    if (x != 0) and (y != (ydim - 1)):
        if arr[y+1][x-1] != 'X':
            arr[y+1][x-1] += 1 # bottom left

    if (y != (ydim - 1)):
        if arr[y+1][x] != 'X':
            arr[y+1][x] += 1 # bottom center


def createMap(mines, x, y):
    global arr

    createBoard(y, x)

    xlist = list(range(0, x))
    ylist = list(range(0, y))

    choiceslist = []

    for xchoice in xlist:
        for ychoice in ylist:
            choiceslist.append((xchoice, ychoice))

    if mines >= len(choiceslist):
        print('bro thats too many mines')
        sys.exit()

    for _ in range(mines):
        choice = random.choice(choiceslist)
        choiceslist.remove(choice)

        placeMine(choice[1], choice[0])

def subtractFlags():
    current_amount = flags.get()
    current_amount = current_amount.replace(('\u2691' + ' '), '')

    flags.set(f'\u2691 {int(current_amount) - 1}')

def addFlags():
    current_amount = flags.get()
    current_amount = current_amount.replace(('\u2691' + ' '), '')

    flags.set(f'\u2691 {int(current_amount) + 1}')
            
def lclick(event):
    global cellsopened

    colorcodes = {1 : 'blue',
                  2 : 'green',
                  3 : 'red',
                  4 : 'purple',
                  5 : 'maroon',
                  6 : 'teal',
                  7 : 'black',
                  8 : 'white',
                  0 : 'gray'}

    widget = event.widget

    info = widget.grid_info()
    row, col = info['row'], info['column']

    current = widget.cget('text')
    arritem = arr[row][col]

    if current != ' ':
        return

    if arritem == 'X':
        gameOver(False)
    else:
        widget.configure(text = str(arritem), fg = colorcodes[arritem])
        cellsopened += 1
        window.after(69, checkWon)

def rclick(event):
    global widget
    widget = event.widget

    info = widget.grid_info()
    row, col = info['row'], info['column']

    current = widget.cget('text')

    if current == ' ':
        widget.configure(text = '\u2691', fg = 'red')
        subtractFlags()
    elif current == '\u2691':
        widget.configure(text = ' ')
        addFlags()

def addGameButtons():
    global zeros

    zeros = 0

    cols = dimensions[1]
    rows = dimensions[0]
    mines = 99

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            
            button = tk.Label(game, width = 1, text = ' ', bg = 'light gray')
            
            if arr[row][col] == 0:
                zeros += 1
                button.config(text = '0', fg = 'gray')

            button.grid(column = col, row = row, padx = 2, pady = 2)
            
            button.bind("<Button-1>", lclick)
            button.bind('<Button-2>', rclick)

def timerUpdate():
    current = timer.get()
    current = current.replace('⏱ ', '')
    
    timer.set(f'⏱ {round(eval(current) + 1)}')

    if won == False:
        window.after(1000, timerUpdate)

def gameOver(won):
    if won == False:
        ans = messagebox.askyesno(message = 'You lost!\n\nDo you wish to play again?')
    else:
        current = timer.get()
        time = current.replace('⏱ ', '')
        ans = messagebox.askyesno(message = f'You won in {time} seconds!\n\nDo you wish to play again?')

    if ans == True:
        restart()

    else:
        window.destroy()
        sys.exit()
        
def checkWon():
    global won
    
    if cellsopened == (dimensions[0] * dimensions[1]) - mines - zeros:
        won = True
        gameOver(True)

def chooseDifficulty():
    dialog_text = 'set theDialogText to "Please select a difficulty:"\ndisplay dialog theDialogText buttons {"Easy (9x9, 10 mines)", "Medium (13x15, 40 mines)", "Expert (30x16, 99 mines)"} default button "Expert (30x16, 99 mines)"'

    out = applescript.run(dialog_text)

    returned = (out.out).replace('button returned:', '')

    if returned == 'Expert (30x16, 99 mines)':
        dimensions = (30, 16)
        mines = 99

    elif returned == 'Medium (13x15, 40 mines)':
        dimensions = (13, 15)
        mines = 40

    elif returned == 'Easy (9x9, 10 mines)':
        dimensions = (9, 9)
        mines = 10

    outres = {'dimensions' : dimensions, 'mines' : mines}

    return outres
    
def main():
    global window, game, flags, flagcounter, infobar, timer, cellsopened, mines, dimensions, won

    won = False

    cellsopened = 0

#========== CON0FIG SECTION ==========
    mines = 99
    dimensions = (16, 30)
#========== CONFIG SECTION ==========

#==============================
    difchoice = chooseDifficulty()

    mines = difchoice['mines']
    dimensions = difchoice['dimensions']
#==============================
    
    createMap(mines = mines, x = dimensions[0], y = dimensions[1])
    
    window = tk.Tk()
    #center(window)
    #window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . middle')
    
    window.config(bg = 'gray')
    window.title('Minesweeper')
    window.resizable(False, False)

    infobar = tk.Frame(bg = 'red')
    infobar.pack(side = 'top')

    game = tk.Frame()
    game.pack(side = 'bottom')

    flags = tk.StringVar()
    flags.set('\u2691' + f' {mines}')

    timer = tk.StringVar()
    timer.set('⏱' + ' 0')

    timecounter = tk.Label(infobar, bg = 'gray', textvariable = timer, width = 5)
    timecounter.propagate(False)
    timecounter.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'w')
    
    flagcounter = tk.Label(infobar, bg = 'gray', textvariable = flags)
    flagcounter.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'e')

    addGameButtons()

    window.after(10, timerUpdate)
    window.mainloop()

def restart():
    global window, game, flags, flagcounter, infobar, timer, cellsopened, mines, dimensions, won
    
    window.destroy()
    
    del window, game, flags, flagcounter, infobar, timer, cellsopened, mines, dimensions, won

    main()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```